# How to verify if a card is banned/limited/semi-limited for an event festival

Tags: yu-gi-oh-master-duel

There are two events coming soon in Yu-Gi-Oh! Master Duel, the Legends Anthology, and the XYZ Festival

[image: Duel page]

If I were to pre-build decks for those events, how do I verify if the card I want to use can be used for the event?

I have already checked the event information and banlist/limited list/semi-limited list, but there is just a bazillion cards in each tab and I didn't see any inputbox where I could type for the name of the card

Ideally, I would like to see the status of the card in the deck building menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the status of the cards in the deck building menu.

1. Go to the event for you which you want to build the deck.
2. Click on *Select Deck* and then *Create New*
3. You are now in the Deck Editor that uses the forbidden/limited list of the event. This can be verified by the icon in the top right. Every forbidden card is not shown in the card list.

[image: Deck Editor of XYZ event]

Alternatively you can use the normal Deck Editor and click on the icon to choose the correct regulation.

[image: Normal Deck Editor]

[image: Select regulation for normal Deck Editor]